# File Not Found at /storage/emulated/0, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, caffe

I am creating an android application for image captioning and have used caffe_jni for it but I'm getting an error:
F0315 Check failed: fd!= -1 (-1 vs. -1) File not found: /storage/emulated/0/cnn_deploy.prototxt
But when I checked the path of the file in my phone, the file is present there and on the same path only.

I am using
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
minSdkVersion 23

```
2021-03-15 12:24:12.639 23207-23207/com.ImageCaptioning A/caffe_jni: F0315 12:24:12.639848 23207 io.cpp:36] Check failed: fd != -1 (-1 vs. -1) File not found: 
/storage/emulated/0/cnn_deploy.prototxt
2021-03-15 12:24:12.639 23207-23207/com.ImageCaptioning A/caffe_jni: terminating.
2021-03-15 12:24:12.640 23207-23207/com.ImageCaptioning A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 23207 (ImageCaptioning), pid 23207 (ImageCaptioning)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: And de Android version of the used devics? And who put that file there? And how?

Comment: Android Version of POCO X2 phone is 11. The git hub repository that I was referring to had provided the link to these files and had instructed to put this file on that path.

Comment: Can be. Those were instructions. But i still dont know who and how that file was written to root of external storage. As the root of external storage is usually not more writable in an Android 11 device.

Comment: I had copied those files on my phone and I have put the same path, as shown in my phone, in the code but still I am getting the error that the file is not found.

Comment: On an Android 11 device apps have no access to files in the root of external storage or when the app is not the owner of the file unless the app obtained all files acces.

Comment: How do I do this? I have given file storage permissions in the manifest file. Whenever the app runs it asks for file storage permission. But as soon as I give it, it says it cannot find the file and the app crashes.

Comment: I did not talk about storage permissions but about android all files access.